# Nginx regex based location directive does not capture whole requested path

Tags: nginx, regex

I have this location directive:

```
    location ~* ^/(_nuxt|_libs|_img|_fonts)/(.*) {
        alias /srv/nuxt/tools/dist/$1;
        try_files /$2 =404;
    }
```

This matches and serves successfully:
`/_img/logo.png`

but not:
`/_libs/AryaBootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css` (returns 404).

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: Try: `root /srv/nuxt/tools/dist; try_files $uri =404;`

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith. The issue was caused by another directive targeting `css` files. I don't understand why that would interfere, since the above block is located above the interfering one in the configuration file.